# I want to get the value of an id from a nested div - jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to obtain the .text() of #inner2

```
<div class="outer" id="outer">

<div id="inner1" class="inner">test1</div>
<div id="inner2" class="inner">test2</div>
<div id="inner3" class="inner">test3</div>


</div>
```

This is the jquery function I am using

```
$('.outer').bind('click',function() {


var one = $('#inner'+x).attr('id');
alert(one);


});
```

The problem is the first #id value is show in the alert.

Thanks

Jean

Comment: Then why are you selecting `'.inner'`? Use `'#inner2'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each` to iterate through the divs with class name inner and then fetch the ids.

```
$('.outer').bind('click',function() {
    $("div.inner").each(function(){
        alert ($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

If you want the id of the clicked one then use event.target

like

```
$('.outer').bind('click',function(e) {
    alert (e.target.id);
    alert($(e.target).text()); 
    // to get text wrap e.target to a jquery object and use .text() on that
});
```

Comment: I want the clicked ones id, not every #id value

Comment: I want to get the text too
heres my code


 var ee = (e.target.id);
 var ee1 = ('#'+ee).text();
 alert(ee1);

does not work though

Answer (score 2):

$('.outer').bind('click',function() {

```
var one = $('#inner2').attr('id');
alert(one);
```

Comment: check the q again, did some changes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.outer').bind('click',function() {


  var one = $('#inner2').text();
  alert(one);


});
```

Comment: check the q again, did some changes

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to retrieve the inner2 on click:

```
$("#outer").click(function() {
  alert($("#inner2").text());
});
```

But if you actually are trying to get the text of the clicked inner div, then the following code will work:

```
$("#outer .inner").click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

If it's to retrieve the ID, then just change `text()` to `attr('id')`.